# R programming - How to create a 2 dimensional array of vectors which are of different lengths

Tags: r

I'm new to the R programming language, and I'm struggling to find the correct data type.

How do you create a matrix of vectors?  Maybe a better way to describe this would be a 2 dimensional array of vectors which are of different lengths.  This is what I'm trying to do:

```
    A = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
    B = c(5, 6, 7)

    C = c(10, 11, 12, 13)
    D = c(14, 15, 16)

    E = c(21, 22, 23, 24)
    F = c(25, 26, 27)

    mat = matrix(nrow=3, ncol=2)

    #This code does not work, but it may give you the gist of what I'm trying to do
    mat[1, 1] = A
    mat[1, 2] = B
    mat[2, 1] = C
    mat[2, 2] = D
    mat[3, 1] = E
    mat[3, 2] = F
```

I would like to get mat to contain the following:

```
            [,1]         [,2]
    [1,]   1 2 3 4       5 6 7
    [2,]   10 11 12 13   14 15 16
    [3,]   21 22 23 24   25 26 27
```

I'm sure this is because I'm using the wrong data type, but I can't find the appropriate one.  I've tried lists, arrays, and data frames, but none of them seem to quite fit exactly what I'm trying to do.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could make an array of lists but this is quite awkward. Are you use you need to store your data this way? what will you be doing with it afterward? Since you are new to R, it's helpful to suggest a more appropriate "R way" to do things

Comment: I'd second the motion to think through how this structure will be used, but it sounds like a `data.frame` with the shorter vectors filled in with `NA`s would work.  It could be coerced to a matrix if necessary when actually used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make a matrix of lists. That would look like

```
mat<-matrix(list(), nrow=3, ncol=2)
mat[[1,1]] <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
mat[[1,2]] <- c(5, 6, 7)
mat[[2,1]] <- c(10, 11, 12, 13)
mat[[2,2]] <- c(14, 15, 16)
mat[[3,1]] <- c(21, 22, 23, 24)
mat[[3,2]] <- c(25, 26, 27)
```

Notice that you have to use double brackets here to extract cells unlike a standard matrix. Also they may not necessarily work the way you expect with standard functions for matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I agreeing with MrFlick that this seems hackish, but I had already done something similar. I wonder if there is any regularity that would allow you to make a more compact structure.

```
 A = list(c(1, 2, 3, 4))
     B = list(c(5, 6, 7))

     C = list(c(10, 11, 12, 13))
     D = list(c(14, 15, 16))

     E = list(c(21, 22, 23, 24))
     F = list(c(25, 26, 27))

     mat = matrix(list(), nrow=3, ncol=2)
     mat[1, 1] = A
     mat[1, 2] = B
     mat[2, 1] = C
     mat[2, 2] = D
     mat[3, 1] = E
     mat[3, 2] = F
 mat
    [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] Numeric,4 Numeric,3
[2,] Numeric,4 Numeric,3
[3,] Numeric,4 Numeric,3
 mat[1,1]
[[1]]
1] 1 2 3 4
```

If all the columns are in the matrix are each of the same length then it might be easier to work with (and display ) a list of two matrices.

```
 mlist <- list(fours = do.call(rbind, mat[,1]),
                threes= do.call(rbind, mat[,2]) )
 mlist
# -----------
$fours
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]   10   11   12   13
[3,]   21   22   23   24

$threes
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    6    7
[2,]   14   15   16
[3,]   25   26   27
```